# Auto post creation

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, post-thumbnails

I've a problem in wordpress that I find automatic posts getting created..
I couldnt figure out what is causing that..
Is this can be from a plugin?
You can see in the picture an example of those posts in trash
Thank you !

[image]

Comment: More likely you've been pwned...

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 solution for you,

1. post by emails is enabled:
   go to **setting** > **writing** and delete the email which you let it to put posts.
2. some body or some plugin is accessing your username and password:
   change theme all include your main email.
3. use a plugin to confirm post publication:
   if you want to publish a post it gets your confirmation
   if it didn't get fixed please disable plugins like plugins that feed your website by instagram.

be careful about plugins.

Good luck.